# how to query in apache drill if the table name contains double quotes

Tags: oracle, apache-drill

Is there any way to query the table in drill, if the table name contains double quotes.

Example:

```
select * from "employee";
```

Comment: Are you sure you have double quotes IN the name of the table? Arent' they used to handle, for example, a table with lower case name?

Comment: yes. it contains double quotes. It is a source table from oracle database.

Comment: Did you try surrounding the table-name with backticks? `backtick`"employee"`backtick`